# React Navigator 5; Tab Navigator and Stack Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am very new to React/React Native...

I am working with React Navigator 5. I have Tab Navigation on Home Screen and I want to create Stack Navigation (with new screens outside Tab Navigation container) for two "tabs" in the Tab Navigation structure.
Is this what's termed "nested navigation"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Root Stack container and tab Container.
If you want to show tabs in stack container give component as tab Container.

E.g. :

```js
import React from "react";

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MyTabs = () => {
  const Navigation = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={BottomNav} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
  
  const BottomNav = () => (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Streams" component={Streams} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Tweets" component={Tweets} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Reported" component={Reported} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Leaderboard" component={Leaderboard} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );

  return <Navigation />
}


export default MyTabs;
```